# Change dynamically value on select 2

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-select2

I have a field Select2 (Jquery) in my PHP page. When I load the page that filed is pupulated using a query. And this works fine.

When i select a value on this filed i would like to populate another field Select2 with a resultset of my query.

The query I want use is something like this:

```
Select * from mytable where id = Select2.val
```

How can I implement it,considering that I wouldn't load my page?

Comment: HTML `select` has nothing to do with SQL

Comment: You would need to make an AJAX call to your server when the user selects a value in the first select, run your query, return the result and then populate your second select.

Comment: Did you solve Your problem ? Maybe you can provide some HTMl that you have to help you ?